# Azure Cloud Services Block all public access with exception

Tags: windows, azure

In Azure cloud services how do I block all public access with exception list ?

I am running Azure cloud service with Windows 2008 R2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up access control list on the endpoints, specifying ranges of IP addresses to allow or block. Currently this is only exposed via PowerShell. You'd do something like this:

```ps
$acl = New-AzureAclConfig

Set-AzureAclConfig -AddRule Permit -RemoteSubnet "1.2.3.0/24" -Order 1 
                        -ACL $acl -Description "my company IP range"

Set-AzureAclConfig -AddRule Deny -RemoteSubnet "5.6.7.0/24" -Order 2 
                        -ACL $acl -Description "that evil hacker"

Get-AzureVM -ServiceName myservice -Name myvm | 
Set-AzureEndpoint -Name http -Protocol tcp -PublicPort 80 -LocalPort 80 -ACL $acl | 
Update-AzureVM
```

Comment: This mean I have to `CREATE A VIRTUAL NETWORK` and then apply this control list on endpoints ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with virtual networks. This is about allowing or denying access to IP ranges that you designate. If you choose to work with virtual networks, then you'll want to align your IP address ranges accordingly, but there's no dependency.

Comment: Is there anymore detail. where is endpoint... would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it part of ServiceDefinition ?

Comment: My apologies - I didn't catch the fact that you're using PaaS (web/worker role instances). ACLs only work with Virtual Machine endpoints. You'll need to set up IP access restriction lists in IIS if using web role instances.

Comment: no problem. I was also looking for IP access restriction lists option in IIS but can't seems to find it in there. I am using web role

Comment: David gave you the answer, but I think this link will help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/11/cloud-service-and-iis-modules.aspx

Comment: @MikeWo Thanks. This is very useful link. I was able to resolve my issue by setting rule on windows firewall.

Comment: @MikeWo Do you know how to configure `Web-IP-Security` module at Startup Tasks. any example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add